# NFC tag emulation is available in iOS app?

Tags: ios, flutter, nfc, core-nfc

Is there any option available in iOS for NFC tag emulation? To make the phone as NFC tags?

Comment: No, HCE and tag emulation is not available to iOS apps

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not up to this point.

Only Wallet/PassKit/Apple Pay have a way to do Host Card Emulation as of now.

There's not an API for third party developers to do HCE.